# Axis 1.6.1 issues while deserializing

Tags: web-services, axis, deserialization

6.1 on JBosss 1.5 ga.  I've developed few webservices in eclipse and deployed as axis archives in axis.war.  The webservices return custom complex objects ( e.g. PurchaseOrder )

I tested the webservices in browser and also in JMeter, they just work fine. Problem is with the JAVA Stubs/clients that I am generating using eclipse plugins. This is what I am doing :

1. Creating a new dynamic web project in eclipse
2. Creating new webservice in this project by selecting the web service implementation class
3. Creating new webservice client for this webservice created in step 2
4. Writing a test class to create instance of the generated proxy class and executing the web service method on it.

Now I confirmed with browser / jmeter that the XML response does resemble the custom complex type, and has correct data in terms of values of the attributes of the complex type. But in the java client class, the output received is NULL. So clearly it is not able to map the xml response to the custom java object on the client side.

Any pointers ?  I can provide more details e.g. actual code / xml o/p etc if required ..

-abhay

Comment: Please note that this web service used to work just fine when used on axis 1.4 and with the client code generated using axis 1.4 plugin in eclipse.

Comment: Can Anyone help me out here pls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rolled back things to Apache Axis 1.4.1 and now the generated code works just fine.  I suspect that there is bug in the Axis code generator plugins for 1.6.1. I have seen too many posts around this issue, but no real resolution as such.

For now, we are happy with Axis 1.4.1 on JBoss 4.2.2 GA  and everything’s  working as desired